# Converting stanford parser typed dependencies to RDF format

Tags: java, rdf

New to Stackoverflow and new to RDF and typed dependencies. But here is what I got so far: I am currently using the Stanford parser to extract typed dependencies from a sentence in a Java program. I wonder how do I convert these typed dependencies to N-triples RDF format?

Later I will write the RDF to a Sesame repository, but that is another question. So what I am really asking is how do I convert Stanford parser typed dependencies to RDF format? I am writing the code in Java in Eclipse.

The typed dependencies for the sentence "John likes coke" will be:

```
[nsubj(likes-2, John-1), root(ROOT-0, likes-2), dobj(likes-2, coke-3)]
```

Comment: As is, this is a bit too broad. Can you provide an actual example (by *editing your question*) of what these typed dependencies look like?

Comment: Done i have added a example

Answer (score 0):

Converting any data to RDF consists of thinking what the things are that you want to represent, and the coming up with a vocabulary (or *ontology*) for them. There may actually be an existing vocbulary out there for this thing that you can reuse, but for the purpose of this question, let's assume you'll mint your own vocabulary.

Since every vocabulary term in RDF is a URI, we will need a namespace first. Let's, for now, settle on `http://example.org/stanford` (prefix `sp`). We'll need vocabulary terms for making something a dependency, for declaring the specific type of dependency, and for expressing the relations between sentence fragments that make up the dependency. To keep it simple, the specific sentence fragment example you gave could be modeled in RDF as follows:

```
 @prefix sp: <http://example.org/stanford/>
 @prefix : <http://example.org/> 

 :nsubj1 a sp:NominalSubject;
         sp:governor :likes-2;
         sp:dependent :john-1 .

 :s1 a sp:Root ;
     sp:dependent :likes-2 .

 :dobj1 a sp:DirectObject ;
        sp:governor :likes-2;
        sp:dependent :coke-3.
```

etc.

To make this happen in Java/Sesame, you should probably write something that reads input from the Stanford Parser, and converts each dependency on a case by case basis to the equivalent RDF terms (tip: it's probably a good idea to declare some constants for your RDF terms), and then either write directly to disk via Sesame's Rio parser/writer, build up an in-memory Model as you go, or even create a simple Repository (basically a database) where you add your RDF data.

I suggest you give this a try, using some of the existing tutorials/documentation that exist for getting started with programming using Sesame. If you get stuck somewhere, you could write a followup question with your specific problem.